# Updated instructions to install Grass Gis on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gis, grass

Just testing the latest version of Cygwin and found that Grass Gis is not part of it. I found some old links (eg. from 2018) giving instructions to install it but I was wondering if there are updated instructions. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: please provide a link to the instuctions you are looking at.

Comment: Have you tried the standard instruction https://grass.osgeo.org/programming7/index.html#Compiling_and_Installing_GRASS_Modules ? Of course you will need to install all the needed *-devel development packages.

Comment: @matzeri thanks for pointing that out, grass82 installed without problems using --prefix and --bindir (instead of --with-bindir).